# Only 1 input hidden form passed out of 2

Tags: php, html

I got this weird issue I'm trying to track where from + keyword of users and redirect on the fly.

The issue is I get only 1 hidden input out of 2 form $from with value but nothing about kw it only transfer 1 hidden input if i change it in places (Put kw hidden input before from hidden input I will get only $kw with value) Never both of them? What is wrong?

This is how I set it:

```
  if (isset($_GET['keyword']) && $_GET['keyword']==$keyword){   

        echo '<html><head></head><body><form action="' . 'http://' . $mainpage . '" method="post" id="form1">

<input type="hidden"  name="from" value="' . $source . '" /></form>
<input type="hidden"  name="kw" value="' . $keyword . '" /></form>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
    document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();</script></body></html>';
        return true; 
        exit();
}
```

And I retreive it using $from or $kw it works only on the on who is first the second one Is like non-existent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ended the `</form>` tag after the first input box. Thus the form ended there and wouldn't submit $kw.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot should have looked more into the code because I was looking all over stackoverflow!